# What is this small white spathed plant in southeast Pennsylvania woodland?

Tags: identification, wildflowers, woodland

This plant was definitely not there last year. It is about 10" tall, and has only two leaves. It looks a lot like a [peace lily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum), but obviously, those aren't naturalized in my area. I would like to know firstly, what is is, and secondly, is it under protection? Many native araceae are.

See photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: that spathe looks so much like a peace lily it's uncanny

Comment: is there even the remotest chance that this is a tropical that someone planted there?  The flowers of an aroid are all similar but this is sooo close

Comment: @kevinsky Well... That's a little weird, but I suppose possible. Why would someone randomly plant a peace lily in my yard?

Comment: The ground around the plant doesn't show signs of recent planting. I found it because I thought it was a piece of trash from afar.

Comment: I've been looking for this plant and all I come up with is Calla pallustris. But the leaves aren't right. Is this the only specimen you've got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *Spathiphyllum wallisii* Regel from *Araceae*. It is a South America native evergreen herbaceous plant.

[image: botanicayjardines.com]

We were talking about this plant in one of our videos ... you can use it perfectly as an indoor plant. How did it get there? The ways of the Lord are inscrutable.

Comment: @J.Musser Why not? I am pretty sure it is a _S. wallisii_

Comment: I thought the big pink thing was part of it. :) I guess this is the closest so far.

Comment: LOL. The pink thing is a new species. @J.Musser the one in the picture was a gift, but I will try to take some new pictures ASAP.